# Viewing $m/m^2$ as a vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am reading Atiyah MacDonald`s Commutative Algebra textbook. In Page 91, next paragraph, I do not understand part of the following:

> If $A$ is a local ring, $m$ its maximal ideal, $k=A/m$ its residue field, the $A-$module $m/m^2$ is annihilated by $m$ and therefore has the structure of a $k-$vector space.

I understand that $m/m^2$ is an $A-$module. I do not get how $m/m^2$ is annihilated by $m$. Why does one need this statement (i.e. annihilation by $m$) to conclude that  $m/m^2$ is a $k-$vector space ? I mean $k$ is a field, so  $m/m^2$ is automatically a vector space as it is a $k-$ module. Finally why is $m/m^2$ Special and not $m/m^n$ for $n>2$?

Comment: Since you think that the space is already a $k$-module, I think I might know the problem.  You are probably thinking of rings constructed like $k[x,y]/I$, which naturally have a $k$-action (and hence so do all their modules).  If that was your thinking, here is a counterexample.  $\mathbb C$ is a quotient of $\mathbb R[x]$, and so you can have a field that is the quotient of a ring such that the ring is NOT an algebra over that field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ is annihilated by $\mathfrak{m}$ because if $x,y\in \mathfrak{m}$ then $xy\in \mathfrak{m}^2$, hence $x\cdot(y+\mathfrak{m}^2)=0+\mathfrak{m}^2$.

Since $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ is an $A$-module on which $\mathfrak{m}$ acts trivially, we can make it an $A/\mathfrak{m}$-module by defining the action
$$ \overline{x}\cdot(y+\mathfrak{m}^2)=x\cdot(y+\mathfrak{m}^2)$$
for $\bar{x}\in A/\mathfrak{m}$ and $x\in A$ representing $\bar{x}$.

In order for this action to be well-defined (i.e. be independent of the choice of $x\in A$ representing $\bar{x}\in A/\mathfrak{m}$), it is essential that $\mathfrak{m}$ act trivially on $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$. This is why we consider $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ rather than say $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^3$.

Answer (score 3):

For an $A$-module $M$ to be a module over $A/I$, we need that multiplication by an element of $A/I$ is actually well defined.  That is, for any $m\in M$, $a\in A$, and $i\in I$, we must have $am=(a+i)m$, or subtracting, that $im=0$.  And conversely, if $IM=0$, then the $A$-module structure of $M$ will pass to an $A/I$-module structure.

Another way of looking at it is that $M/IM$ is a module over $A/I$, but if $IM=0$, you have $M\cong M/IM$.

As for why $I/I^2$ is annihilated by $I$ (I'm using $I$ since this doesn't depend on using maximal ideals), that just follows from the fact that an element of $I/I^2$ is of the form $i+I^2$, and if you multiply by $j\in I$, you get $ij+I^2$, but by the definition of $I^2$, $ij\in I^2$, and so $ij+I^2=0+I^2$.

And $I/I^2$ isn't special.  You will have that $I^k/I^{k+1}$ is an $A/I$-module for all $k$.  However, $I/I^{k+1}$ is only a module over $A/I^k$.

Answer (score 1):

$m/m^2$ is anhilated by $m$ i.e for every $a\in m, x\in m/m^2, ax=0$ so the map $A\times m/m^2\rightarrow m/m^2, (a,x)\rightarrow ax$ defines a map $A/m\times m/m^2\rightarrow m/m^2, ([a],x)\rightarrow ax$,  where $[a]$ is the class of $a\in A$ in $A/m=k$.